# Передача массива из php в js

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, массивы, post

Как передать массив со значениями из php в js как ответ к post-запросу(!)? И как извлечь значения. Гуглю уже не один день, ничего не нашел, передаю вот так:

Php:

```
$data = [
        "idp" => $idp,
        "p" => $p
    ];
    echo(json_encode($data));
```

Js:

```
$.post("../php/video.php", {"dt": str},
                            function(arr){
                                arr = $.parseJSON(arr);
                                var idp = arr[0];
                                var p = arr[1];
                                alert(arr);
                                alert(idp + p);
```

Но получается это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите пример `$idp, $p` того что в них находиться.

Comment: $idp - 66942 $p - LoginName

Answer (score 2):

Если получаете `JSON` не нужно прасить, если строка то нужно.

```js
// Предположим в них ($idp, $p) находятся массивы...
var jj = '{"idp":["soething","other","else"],"p":["sss","ddd","hhh"]}';

// In case you have JSON and not string you don't have to parse it...
// var jj = {"idp":["soething","other","else"],"p":["sss","ddd","hhh"]}; 

$.post("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", {
    "dt": "something"
  },
  function(arr) {
    arr = $.parseJSON(jj); // <--- No need to do this in JSON case

    // Keys are names idp and p
    var idp = arr.idp; //arr[0]; <--- No number value key
    var p = arr.p; //arr[1]; <--- No number value key
    //----------------------------------------------------------------

    console.log(arr);
    console.log(idp + ' | ' + p);

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Пытался делать тоже самое, выводило undefined

Comment: Данные вообще приходят? `console.log` используйте, вместо `alert`.